# Can't use "let" keyword in Safari Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari, ecmascript-6

I don't understand the best way to use "let" keyword...

- In IE11 and Chrome45 I can use it fine
- In Safari8.0.4, like in older versions of Chrome, it gives the error "unexpected use of reserved word 'let'"
- In Firefox the let keyword only works inside `<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7"/>`, but this script type isn't even recognized as Javascript in IE11, Chrome45, Safari8.

Here's a JSFiddle that shows it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/p6cgtyg6/1/

So -- I don't mind requiring users to use modern versions of their browsers.

And I don't mind excluding Safari if there honestly is no version of Safari that supports this keyword. (Is that really true? Why does everyone spend all their time griping about IE when Safari seems so much worse in ES6 terms? Have I missed something?).

But how should I allow "let" to work in Firefox while not preventing Chrome/IE? (I haven't yet found links from people griping about how Firefox script tag behaves differently from Chrome, and I'd have expected more complaints, so I figure I must have missed something obvious...)

Comment: Why is lack of support for *let* an issue? ECMA-262 6th Edition is still only a draft, many of its features are not supported by all browsers. There are some ES5 features that are not supported yet.

Comment: "for (var i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
   $("<span/>").text(c[i].title).click(function() { DoStuff(c[i]); }).appendTo(p);
}" -- this code will behave wrongly. The easiest and cleanest codefix is to use "let" inside the for loop. I don't really want to write yuckier code now when ES6 is shortly around the corner and is mostly supported ad will solve the problem nicely...

Comment: @LucianWischik no need for `let` in that case, though. many easier ways rather than adding a dependency on a 6=>5 compiler.

Comment: Restricting accessibility to your web site to a couple of the most recent browser versions because you want to use a new feature of a draft specification is your prerogative of course. But your predicament is entirely self imposed. ;-)

Comment: @RobG it's an issue because time marches on, ES6 is now standard, and safari is the new IE. so the question still remains and is no longer self-imposed.

Comment: @worc—but use of *let* is entirely gratuitous, there is no good reason to use it instead of *var*. It has been introduced for convenience when transpiling other languages to javascript. Javascript applications with over 100,000 lines have been written without *let*, it's use is unnecessary (*written using Safari 10.0, which supports let*). ;-)

Comment: @RobG be as smug as you want, `let` is here and there's nothing gratuitous or unnecessary about using a language feature when the situation calls for it.

Comment: @worc—no need to get personal. Whether to use a particular feature or not should be based on rational consideration of the pros and cons. The only reason the OP has put forward to use it is "*I want to*" (hence my use of [*gratuitous*](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=define+gratuitous&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=c6jtV6uFO83N8geF9oDIBg)). However, there are real downsides from lack of browser support. Some devices may not be able to upgrade to a browser that supports *let*, so it's not necessarily the user's fault that they are using an older browser.

Comment: @RobG you made it personal by assuming you knew best and by assuming there were no non-gratuitous uses for `let`. that was never and still is not within the scope of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Concerning Safari 8, it's just [not supported](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#let_basic_support_(strict_mode)) ; for that browser, I'd recommend using [Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel).

If you have the gut feeling that [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=932517) won't be fixed anytime soon* then you could have a script that detect Firefox which would then inject your script(s) with the appropriate value for the type attribute.

As a side note, I would advise not to use let blocks—unless you wanna use [this transpiler](https://github.com/getify/let-er)—nor let expressions which [will be dropped](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1023609).

<sub>* fixed in Firefox 44</sub>

Answer (score 4):

`let` is a part of ECMAScript 6 specification, and ECMAScript 6 itself is in 'draft' status. Even in its incomplete form its features aren't supported fully by actual browser versions.

Since you want to dive into ES6 today for production, your best bet is to use ES6 to ES5 transpiler, most prominent ones are [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler), which are available as both CLI and packages for the build system of your choice. There are online tools for [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/) and [Traceur](https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html) to try them out. And [Scratch JS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scratch-js/alploljligeomonipppgaahpkenfnfkn) extension for Chrome uses both Babel and Traceur and is excellent for developing and compiling ES6 scripts if the build system is not an option.

Here is [up-to-date comparison table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) that embraces ES6 feature support in both browsers and ES6 compilers.

And here is [a great collection](https://github.com/addyosmani/es6-tools) of ES6-related tools.

Answer (score 1):

See browser compatability of this ES6 keyword.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility

Also [see this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046635/javascript-es6-cross-browser-detection) for ES6 feature detection.

Comment: Thanks. That confirms that Safari8 doesn't have any kind of "let" support. I wonder about the second part of my question -- what is the right way to use "let" in a page that works in both Firefox and Chrome? Your ES6-feature-detection post was interesting but didn't touch on this aspect.

Comment: WIthout a server generating the scripts tags I can't see how it can be done nicely across browsers - in chrome it works with a script tag like `script type="application/javascript" version="1.7"` and even without the version,  but in firefox it needs `script type="application/javascript;version=1.7"`