# If ECMA 6 is standard, then why simple script isn't supported in main browsers?

Tags: javascript

Since the ECMA 6 become an official standard three months ago (June 2015),
[ECMA6 reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-let-and-const-declarations)
how can it be that it's syntax is still not supported in main browsers?

From my own checks, I've found that even simple keywords like: let (block scoped variable) seems not to work not in IE11, FF or even Safari

Does anyone have an information, or at least can put to to the right direction?

I've found this stackoverflow question  :
[Firefox cannot use let word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194024/cant-use-let-keyword-in-safari-javascript)

But it seems to be out of date, since it's not a draft for a few months already.

Comment: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Browsers are slow to fully support new stuff. They usually do it bit by bit. `let` is probably rather low on the priority list.

Comment: If you want to use es6 features right now, your best bet is to compile to es5. I would recommend Babel (https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: @dfsq Wow, what are they doing with mouse events on that page? Moving the cursor above the table noticably slows down my browser!

Comment: It's on purpose. ES6 works for everyone else but you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the most complete compatibility table http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ I've ever seen.

Comment: Interesting, note the footnote 13 for the `let` keyword in FF on that table. Maybe it is supported in FF...

Comment: It is supported, only if you specify it in script's declaration.

Comment: I've marked it as accepted, since it's the best answer. But sad that official standard release and an actual release are still not the same. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question here: [When will I Be Able to Use ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355486/when-will-i-be-able-to-use-es6-in-a-browser)

The top answer is very helpful. Pretty much by the end of 2015 there will be support for ES6. Right now you need to turn experimental javascript on your browser for ES6 code to function.