# How to test if browser supports js ES6 Class?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, browser-support

My js classes works fine in Chrome, but when I test in IE for example, the script fails as expected, giving an ugly syntax error.
Is there someway to test if the clients browser can handle ES6 Classes in javascript?

Comment: And what would you do if not?

Comment: Btw, `try { eval('"use strict"; class foo {}'); } catch (e) { console.log(e); }`

Comment: The problem is, browsers support only some features of ES6 at the moment. You can check which browser supports features you need [here] (https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Comment: What are you planning to do if you find it's not supported?

Comment: @KrystianLaskowski ES6 detection, better ES6 features detection? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046635/javascript-es6-cross-browser-detection **not library js for ES6 features detection?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically you could

```
try { eval('"use strict"; class foo {}'); } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
```

practically I don't see it's reasonable to prefer it to transpiling at least these days.

Comment: Put the eval code in parenthesis for it to work in Firefox.

Comment: View this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046635/javascript-es6-cross-browser-detection