# How to specify the version of Javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

As the new JavaScript ES6 is launched. I am trying to know how do I specify the version.

Suppose, if I want to use HTML5, I declare at the top of the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Similarly, if I think to use jQuery then I do use jQuery 2.1.4 or any I do it the src pointing to below url

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js
```

This is how we write js in html.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 //js
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"> </script>
```

How do I specify that version **ES6** should be used for the script, in case it is not supported by browser, fall back to ES5.

Comment: I don't think the browsers will have two versions of the JavaScript interpreter on board; they'll only use the one. So if you want to use ES6, you will have to check from within JavaScript.

Comment: @MrLister, okay..thats fine. but how do I specify the version number to be used in the script. Suppose, I want to use the new features of ES6, & I want the browser to use ES6, if they donot support thats fine to me

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to check from within a JavaScript routine to see what the browser is capable of.

Comment: Hey, who is downvoting this? It's a very good question, and on topic.

Comment: @MrLister..even I am surprise who has downvoted, but thats not an issue.

Comment: @MrLister, suppose I want to use `const` feature of ES6, in a normal html, hence I want to declare that version ES6 to be used for the script. so how do I do that

Comment: @pkhode You can't do that. There is [`<script type=module>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-script-element:module-script) but that's not quite the same.

Comment: @RGraham I found this link, but not sure how much it is correct 
http://www.webreference.com/js/column26/version.html

Comment: You can use feature - detection... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046635/javascript-es6-cross-browser-detection)

Comment: Again, you don't need to tell the browser to use ES6. Either it supports it or it doesn't. If it supports it, it'll work automatically.

Comment: If you want to use `const`, you can already use it in most modern browsers. If you want to use it any given browser, you'll want to either transpile it use a library that polyfills it for you.

Within the UA, there's no distinction if it's ES5 or ES6, so you can't actually detect for it.

Comment: @CyrilIselin, if I need 5-6 features of ES6, you says that for every feature will do that. That can be overhead

Comment: @CyrilIselin Not for syntax you can't. And pkhode that is old information, there's no way to target ES6 like that

Comment: @EmmaRamirez, I am just giving an instance of one features, There are several good features

Comment: Does it seem backwards that browsers do not specify what version number of JavaScript that they support?

Answer (score 6):

As others have said: The browser will use whatever JavaScript engine it has built in ... be that 3, 5 or some version of 6.

*While there **used** to be a way to specify a version of JavaScript using the `lang` parameter, that has been obsolete for at least 10 years, and only mattered for JavaScript versions 1 and 2, which behaved quite differently.*

If you need to make sure that your code runs on an older JavaScript engine, you must use a transpiler, such as Babel. The resultant code will run on ES3, ES5 or 6.

Your other options are:

- Write ES6 code and where it runs, it runs. Where it doesn't -- oh well.
- Write ES5 code and run it everywhere.  (Well, everywhere modern.)

Answer (score 3):

One way to use different versions of your script is to load them depending on what features are present. Say, the `hypot` function in the Math library.
For instance with jQuery:

```js
if (typeof Math.hypot == "undefined")  // Is hypot defined?
   $.getScript('old_routines.js');     // No, load old library
else
   $.getScript('new_routines.js');     // Yes, assume ES6 and load new library
```

Comment: Useful.But I would like to know What is this `SpecialObject`?

Comment: Does http://es6-features.org/ help? Wait, I can't seem to find `SpecialObject` on that site. Stand by.

Comment: did you get   that puts light on it?

Comment: @pkhode Nope. Just a lot of code examples that use it! But those routines flag all the latest browsers as not ES6 compatible, so there is something fishy about that. Maybe it's better to check for something else, say `typeof Math.hypot`.

Comment: Um... "SpecialObject" is just a placeholder for whatever feature you want to check. So if you want to use, for example, the FileWriter API, you'd write `typeof FileWriter` and so on.

Comment: @Juhana That makes an incredible lot of sense, but not many people (such as the author of [this codepen](http://codepen.io/kedomonzter/pen/WQBeZQ)), seem to realise that.