# How can I test for Ecmascript 6 in the browser in one line of code?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I check to see the user is running ES6 or greater in one line of code?

I am not talking about transpiling code from ES6 to JavaScript I'm talking about checking if the browser supports ES6 or marking code as ES6. Doesn't JavaScript script tag have a version and we can specify EcmaScript6?

According to this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) I can set a version number in Firefox but it indicates this is not a standard feature,

> ...in Firefox you can use advanced features such as let statements and
>   other features in later JS versions, by using
>   type=application/javascript;version=1.8. Beware, however, that as
>   this is a non-standard feature, this will most likely break support
>   for other browsers, in particular Chromium-based browsers.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046635/javascript-es6-cross-browser-detection

Comment: The problem with detecting ES2015+ features that are syntax changes (arrow functions, generators, async/await) is that, you can't use this new syntax in the file where you are trying to detect if this new syntax is available - I guess you could dynamically load differing js depending on availability of such syntax or not, but that would mean you have ES5 and ES2015+ versions of the same code on the server anyway ... presumably using a transpilier to go from modern to old ... just use the old versions everywhere for now

Comment: @JaromandaX If I can't detect ES6 using JavaScript then how do I detect it? My app requires ES6 features. I'm not transpiling to JS.

Comment: have you read the accepted answer in the question linked to in the first two comments ... that's how you do it

Answer (score 1):

Try looking up these links 1st.

1. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/
2. http://caniuse.com/#search=ecmascript
3. http://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class

Then try using object detection in JavaScript to see if any number of desired features are available or not.

Also look for Browser Stats tables, like this link:
http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/default.asp

Usually companies don't care about the browser when < 1% of their web visitors use it. It's too costly for them to develop patches, when 99% of the people won't be using that patch.