# Check basic ES6 support without "unsafe-eval"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, content-security-policy

I'd like to know if the browser supports ECMAScript 6 (ES6) (basic support is enough) but also I want to use reasonable Content Security Policy (CSP) headers. The solution which I have so far, see "[Check if a browser supports ES6](https://www.bram.us/2016/10/31/checking-if-a-browser-supports-es6)", requires `'unsafe-eval'`. So do solutions in answers to "[Javascript ES6 cross-browser detection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29046635/2738262)". Any idea to get around this?

```
    var supportsES6 = function() {
      try {
        new Function("(a = 0) => a");
        return true;
      }
      catch (err) {
        return false;
      }
    }();
```

Comment: As long as you control the string that is passed to `new Function` (which is clearly the case here), it is not unsafe. Note that ES6 support is not a Yes/No thing: ES6 concerns many different aspects, and JavaScript engines typically support few, some or many of the ES6 related features.

Comment: Not using `unsafe-eval` sounds perfectly reasonable to me. If you want to use `eval`, that's fine. Not allowing it doesn't really make your page much more secure anyway.

Comment: @trincot How does one express that "it is not unsafe" machine-readably using Content Security Policy?

Comment: @Bergi duped this question to [Javascript ES6 cross-browser detection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29046635/2738262), but I don't see how it "already has an answer [t]here". Its answers by Marco Bonelli, Martin Wantke, and hydroper require either no CSP or a CSP including `'unsafe-eval'`. The answer by Casey detects ES6 _modules_, not ES6 _syntax_, and the answer by Andy Chen detects WebKit, not ES6.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, @DamianYerrick, but instead of testing the support for arrow syntax, you could test for the presence of ES6-specific globals or methods, like the `Promise` object or the `Object.assign` method? That way you don't need to weaken the CSP.

Comment: @trincot If the question is "Can I load a particular ES6 script without a syntax error, or do I have to fall back to a transpile?", testing for ES6 globals or methods will provide a misleading answer if a polyfill emulating the ES6 functionality has been loaded. It's not _quite_ as bad as testing for a browser version, but it's not the most precise either.

Comment: Does checking need to be synchronous or can it be asyncronous?

Comment: Like I said before, ES6 support is not a yes/no thing. You wrote that basic support was enough? What does that mean? As far as I know there is no "basic" standard. JS engines vary in their support.

Comment: @DamianYerrick I still thinks the accepted answer on the former duplicate perfectly answers this question: "*feature detection of newly introduced syntaxes (like arrow functions) can only be done using the eval() function or other equivalents*". It goes on to explain why and also lists some reasonable alternatives if you are not looking for syntax support.

Answer (score 0):

You could test for native support of `Symbol.toStringTag` which wasn't added to browsers until after most other ES6 functionality and which if supported would mean that ES6 is also supported:

```
function isES6() {
    return typeof Symbol=="function"
        && typeof Symbol.toStringTag=="symbol"
}
```

This would not be enough if you needed to test for support of ES6 modules. But it's good enough if you just need to confirm support of new ES6 features and syntax like arrow functions.

And best practice is that you shouldn't use this if feature detection can be used instead.

Answer (score -1):

I would assume the reason you want to detect es6 support, is either to decide if to deliver es6 code or es5 or to show an error. the most easiest way to do this would be to make use of the es module system

```
<script type="module" src="script.es6.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="script.es5.js"></script>
```

Browsers that support es6 will load `script.es6.js` and ignore `script.es5.js`, and browsers that does not support es6 will ignore `script.es6.js` and load `script.es5.js`