# How does the javascript: protocol differ from standard browser JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, protocols

According to the link below, the javascript: URL

> Specifies one or more semicolon-separated JavaScript statements.

It is common for modern JavaScript code to use line breaks instead of semicolons. Can this be done using the javascript: protocol?

I want to run any code using this protocol(Take the contents of any isolated JavaScript file and easily convert to javascript: format), so I would like to know of any differences with standard browser JavaScript and how it would be possible to retain white space characters.

Note, I am using Google Chrome, so if there are differences by browser, Google Chrome information would be preferred.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767736(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

it is one misconception, that one could omit semicolons - except in the last line of a statement - else not. when inline-ing JavaScript, (which is in general a bad practice, because it produces code that is painful to maintain)... only the last one statement might lack the semicolon.

for example, taken from the MSDN:

```
<A HREF="javascript:alert('JavaScript Link!');">
```

could be expressed as:

```
<A HREF="javascript:alert('JavaScript Link!')">
```

but as soon as more than one statement is being inserted there - they need to be separated with a `;`.

if you really have to inline JS into HTML attributes, at least make it custom function calls - else you add quite some handicap, because JS syntax highlighting does not function on an element attribute - which is being represented as a string.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I made a slight update to the question because I feel there may be some confusion. Also, I would like to mention that javascript: can be executed from the address bar and directly using javascript.

Comment: @DamienGolding in order to retain white-space characters, one can escape them alike `"\n"` (notice the double quotes there)... in order to represent newline within a single line. here is a chart with all of them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/special-characters-javascript ...however, this code will always run in the global scope `window`.

Comment: The solution was actually quite simple. I added an answer. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

There actually seems to be no problem if encodeURI is used.
Executing the following in developer console works(Tested in Google Chrome):

```
location.href=encodeURI(`javascript:

function demoFunction(){
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2//No semicolon
    var c = 3/*No semicolon*/

    return (a+b+c);
}
alert(demoFunction())

`);
```

Comment: this code is not too portable because it won't run on elder browsers - unless providing backwards-compatibility.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Please explain where and why it will not work?

Comment: because this is ECMA6 ? syntax - and there are countless devices & users which may not be able to simply update their browser for various reasons... eg. compliance, embedded devices, etc. most people have no clue how far government & military lag behind... large organizations in general. the `encodeURI` part is certainly correct, but omitting the semicolons is no portable code, because it only works when the browser interprets the wrongful syntax correctly.

Comment: @MartinZeitler As in the question, this is personally concerning Google Chrome. For other environments it is possible to use Babel. This is an example for showing that it works so the value(format) of location.href is most important. The example can be achieved via other methods such as loading a file or AJAX. Whether the code omitting semicolons is wrong or not is not of importance. I want the standard code and javascript: protocol code to work identically.

Comment: @MartinZeitler the key point in this answer is to encodeURI the return character needed for the auto-insertion of the `;` character. So you could also just use good ol' plain string as long as you encodeURI `\n` to `%0A`

Comment: just see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29046739/549372 ...writing client-side JavaScript only to run it in the local console is rather one niche application. while when omitting the semicolons, some packers might also produce broken code. would say, latest features without backwards compatibility make sense on one intranet, where on can be certain all use eg. the latest version of Chrome. but on the internet, one cannot assume that.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I do not expect people to use my example in production code, it is just a proof that it works and how.

Comment: well ...currently, there is not a single one browser which supports 100% of the suggested features... https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ - and the portability is ordinary quite an important aspect - except when only targeting one single browser.

Comment: @MartinZeitler This code works in Google Chrome. Regarding "portability" see my last comment.