# Is there a term like "straight" or "clean" for ES6 libraries without transpiling?

Tags: ecmascript-6, naming-conventions

I am currently porting some ES5 libraries I wrote to learn the ES6 syntax.
I am choosing to NOT transpile because I do not want the toolchain headache and I want to learn the syntax as how the browsers respect it NOT the compiler/parser.

example:
https://github.com/cbuteau/typetools

So has anyone come up with a short term to describe JUST ES6.
So I can tag my repository and package when I publish appropriately.

Also if anyone has figured out how to perform code coverage on ES6 without transpiling reach out to me directly in a SO DM or github DM.

Comment: Which parts of ES6? Do you mean modules? Or do you just want to not care and throw a syntax error if someone tries to load your code over CDN in IE8?

Comment: Your comment about code coverage should be an entirely separate question.

Comment: whatevs @zero298...I figured this might attract people wanting to help and I threw it in there....

to answer your helpful question...just focusing on what is the correct syntax for FF and Chrome...  so modules, arrows, const...all of it...I don't see any reason to use async or await in the lib I referenced but that could change if I got feedback...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a term for for being purely forward compliant from ES6.  The closest thing that might work is writing your code as a module with `import`/`export` syntax and telling your users that the only way to use it is through the module system.  Modules are inherently ES6 only.

That being said, tagging your repository as a "module" probably won't alleviate the confusion since node has always had "modules".  Possibly "esm" or "ECMAScript module" might be better as that's how [esm](https://github.com/standard-things/esm) ("The brilliantly simple, babel-less, bundle-less ECMAScript module loader" describes the module system introduced by ES6.

At the same time, maybe have a look at this question [Javascript ES6 cross-browser detection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29046635/691711) especially the bit about how to do syntax targeting.  The most straightforward way to signal to library consumers that your library will only run in ES6 compliant contexts is to just let the engine throw a syntax error due to your code.

Comment: Should we use this to come up with a term.
I like the sound of PURE ES6....

I am thinking more from a documentation standpoint in the README.
So people do not get the librabry and add issues..."Doesn't load"

Oh and thank you for your clear response...

Comment: @cbuteau I think a problem you may run into is newer features that get added over time. Browsers are starting to add features without even associating versions. Would you forgo the new null coalesce and optional chaining syntax features in your library to stay "ES6 pure" or would you want a new term to describe compatibility with them?

Comment: I think we determined there is no way to clarify that something is class syntax versus prototypes and will only work in browsers supporting such.  I have accepted this and moved on.  I have not tried null coalesce but eventually want to use optional chaining.